# Windows 10 AAD Azure ad domain joined & SMB share

Tags: network-share, windows-10, server-message-block, entra-id, mappeddrive

I have a number of Windows 10 clients domain joined to azure ad, I still have a local Windows 2012 r2 server onsite with a number of shares i wish to map to from the windows 10 clients. Bu if I try accessing the UNC path from a client I get "you do not have permissions to access the server", if I add the credentials in to credential manager.
If I try to use the drive map wizard it shows the "Network folder is mapped using a different user" even though there re no other connections to the server.

Comment: Are the machines also domain joined locally? Is the 2012 server also Azure AD joined?

Comment: The windows 10 are joined to azure ad, the 2012 server is a domain controller although I can demote it to a stand alone as no clients are using that domain anymore.

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t have the machines joined to the domain anymore? I know you can run all cloud, but if you are running an on-premise server and domain controller / file server, the computers can be connected to both onpremise domain and azure AD in hybrid. The only way I can think of otherwise to do this is to join the file server to the Azure domain. Even then I’m not familiar with access control using only AAD, sorry.

Comment: You can't add 2012 to azure domains,, the server is going to go at some point , I just wonder how people would use a nas with SMB shares, or a shared network printer if you can't connect to local resources when logged in with a cloud account .

Comment: Well you can access local resources, but if you’re going to have any form of authentication there has to be a central directory of some sort. Typically that is a domain controller. Otherwise there need to be individual accounts created on the server, or NAS or whatever it is. You’ll need to see what access control you can use on a Windows file server with AAD.

Comment: If I add credentials to credential manager , and type the Inc path in it says I don't have access , if I try to map it says it already exists, iif it was not using a cloud account  and not domain joined it would connect using this methed, connecting to a server is not the issue it just seems to not work if logged in using a cloud account, the problem is I can't access local resources

Comment: I also agree with Appleoddity's opinion. This issue may caused by your Sever's environment. I can access SMB shares from my windows10 device which logined via Azure AD account. But I used another credential.

Comment: Are the users logging on to the Azure Domain Joined PC synched from your On-prem domain? If yes, there should not be any problems accessing SMB shares on your server. Br,

Comment: No they are not synced , unexpected windows to ask for credentials if it can't access the shared drive, it doesn't so I have no way of mapping a drive, the domain will be going soon so I'm not adding any more devices to this domain, I believe windows 10! when azure joined should act like any older OS and ask for username and password when accessing a share whether the share is in a domain or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered this question before. Essentially you are expecting to be able to get rid of your on premise domain controller (DC) because you can join you laptops and workstations to Azure.

That is an incorrect understanding of Azure.

You still need a DC (a virtual machine (VM) in the cloud or a physical server).

That DC has Azure Active Directory (AAD) Connect installed and configured on it. That creates an account in AD that synchronizes accounts and passwords with AAD.

When a computer joined to AAD logs in it sends the login request to AAD. AAD then validates that authentication request against the information synchronized from AD.

So if you have workstations and laptops joined to AAD and they try to access a share on a server that is in a different domain than what AAD synchronizes with you are going to need to provide credentials that exist in the server which hosts the resources you are trying to access.

There are a few right ways to do this and I will give you two.

1. If the clients are in a single location and will always be in the same location as the DC then join them to the domain regularly. For clients that will be used in other locations join those computers to AAD and install AAD Connect in the DC.
2. If you want to move all of the servers out of your office spin up a VM for your DC in Azure and deploy a cloud firewall in front of your VM. Create a Site-to-Site Virtual Private Network (VPN) between the cloud firewall and your office firewall. Now join computers that will always be in the office to the domain like normal, join computers that are going to be used remotely to AAD, and install AAD Connect on the DC.

Answer (score 2):

After much research and testing, here's the solution that worked for me!
This is how to connect to a local network resource (such as an SMB share, local server, etc.) from an AzureAD connected Windows 10 Pro computer, logged in as the end user:

1) Search 'cred' and open Credentials Manager

2) Choose Windows Credentials

3) Click 'Add a Windows credential'

- Internet or network address: enter the network location, such as a LAN IP address or network share
- User name: domain\User
- Password: enter user's password

---

Example:

- Internet or network address: \fileserver\share
- User name: example.local\Administrator
- Password: admin password

---

With the above in place, Windows will check the credentials against the local domain server (in this case example.local) and grant or deny access to the network share.

Comment: I managed to connect to Samba from an Azure joined computer by using the command line.

```net use * \\server\path```



https://thewindev.net/connecting-to-samba-from-an-azure-joined-computer-aad